# I am writing a query to extract results from a table with a condition to exclude some results from the table

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to extract results from a table with a condition to exclude some results from the table.

Ex: I have a table with students name column (100 students).   I want to run a query  to extract details of 95 students and exclude 5 students. Could you help me out with this?.

Here is more information:

Thanks for your answer. I am sorry if my question was unclear.

Here is more information what I am trying to run.

I have a task queue ID

> Task Queue 1 = Documents manually processed.
>    Task Queue 2 = Documents exported to another application

Task Queue 2 includes documents manually processed and documents automatically processed to another application. I am trying to run total number of documents exported to another application (Task Queue 2) and exclude Task Queue 1 from these results.

I tried the code as given below , but I did not get any results.

```
Select WorkQueueHistory.id from WorkQueueHistory where 
TaskId='2' NOT IN( Select WorkQueueHistory.id from WorkQueueHistory where TaskId='20') and 
creationStampUtc>='2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
and creationStampUtc<='2013-12-31 00:00:00.000'
```

WorkqueueHistory is the table
TaskID is the task number

I want to run results from taskID 2 but want to exclude task ID 20.

could you help me out with this?.

Comment: Based on what condition? Usually this is accomplished with a  `WHERE` condition....

Comment: What tables do you have? What is the condition on which you want to select? Given table, expected results? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What criteria do you have for excluding the 5 students? That is kind of the key here

For example, if you wanted to exclude all of the men you might do

```
SELECT Name, Gender FROM Students WHERE Gender = 'Male'
```

Or to exclude those called Mark maybe

```
SELECT Name FROM Students WHERE Name LIKE '%Mark %'
```

But it depends on the criteria

UPDATE: *with specifics to update, something along these lines (without seeing your table)

```
SELECT q2.DocName 
  FROM Queue2 q2
 WHERE q2.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Queue1)
```

Assuming you have an Id column or something which is common across both queues - you need some common identifier be it name or Id

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry if my question was unclear.

Here is more information what I am trying to run.

I have a task queue ID

Task Queue 1 = Documents manually processed.
Task Queue 2 = Documents exported to another application

Task Queue 2 includes documents manually processed and documents automatically processed to another application. I am trying to run total number of documents exported to another application (Task Queue 2) and exclude Task Queue 1 from these results.

Comment: @user3206610 you should edit you question and add this extra information